# Change Date & Time Format in AMPScript Populated content

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, code

I'm working on an e-mail in SalesForce Marketing Cloud that uses AMPScript to populate and event start time. The data extension field that populates the AMP Script is set as a text field, unfortunately that means that times are being set to include seconds instead of just hours and minutes.

Here's what I started with:`%%StartTime%%` which populates as 2:00:00 PM

I tried the replace function`%%=Replace(@StartTime,':00',' ')=%%`however this left the field blank.

So I tried `%%=FormatDate(%%StartTime%%, "HH:MM", "en-US")=%%` and `%%=FormatDate(2:00:00 PM, "HH:MM", "en-US")=%%` was returned.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be this without the double `%%`:

```
%%=FormatDate(StartTime, "hh:mm tt, "en-US")=%%
```

or better:

```
%%[

var @startTime
set @startTime = AttributeValue("StartTime")
set @startTime = FormatDate(@startTime, "hh:mm tt", "en-US")

]%%

It's currently %%=iif(empty(@startTime), "HAMMER TIME!", @startTime)=%%
```

Reference: [MSDN DateTimeFormatInfo Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx)

Comment: Awesome, but now the following displays:  
14:01 en-U0

I removed the CultureCode and was left with just the time, but no AM or PM. How would I change this to 12hr from 24hr?

Comment: I've updated my answer above.  I think the mask should be `hh:mm tt`, not `HH:MM`.

Comment: Seriously, you're a major help.

Last bit, your update worked, but now for some reason the time is being set as 201pm vs. 200pm. Below is the output:

02:01 PM

Also, is there a way to have the 0 be conditional so it's not displaying a time like the above?

Answer (score 2):

Adam had most of it right but you're getting the same error as I am - you're getting 14:01 because it looks like AMPscript is not differentiating between cases in `formatdate()`, so your mm is getting displayed as a 2 digit MM month (january in this case as it's the default start month if unspecified). I couldn't get AMPscript to recognize cased date/time format strings so my workaround which is not ideal was to do the following:

`%%=DatePart(v(@begin_time), 'hour')=%%`:`%%=DatePart(v(@begin_time), 'minute')=%%` `%%=FormatDate(v(@begin_time), 'tt')=%%`

That ends up getting me 2:00 PM

**EDIT** doing DatePart to return Minutes only results in a single 0 which is not helpful when displaying the time. Same works for 'mi' as well.

Answer (score -2):

Your were using an ampscript string call (%%) inside an ampscript block. This is not necessary.

Below the correct code to use :

```
%%=FormatDate(startTime,"", "hh:mm tt")=%%
```